# Multiple datatree Child fields

Tags: tabulator

How to create two datatree from two child field in tabulator ?

I tried this but it takes Column2 to make the datatree.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
data: table,
dataTree:true,
dataTreeChildField:"Column1",
dataTreeChildField:"Column2"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid JavaScript object, when you add two properties to an object with the same key, the second one overrides the first.

It is not possible to assign two fields as holding children, but you could create an extra hidden column in your table with a mutator that fills it with the children from the other two columns:

```
//child data mutator
var childDataMerge = function(value, data, type, params, component){
    if(Array.isArray(data.Column1) && Array.isArray(data.Column2)){
        return data.Column1.concat(data.Column2);
    }else{
        return [];
    }
}

//define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: table,
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeChildField:"_children",
    columns:[
        //your normal columns go here

        //data mutation row
        {field:"_children", visible:false, mutatorData:childDataMerge}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift reply!

Comment: Happy to help :) If this advice works for you, would you mind marking it as the answer so it can help others out too, cheers